# Multithreaded Poor Man's Debugging in Scala

Tags: scala, debugging, logging, trace

Occasionally I want to print values, arrays, expressions, etc. quickly and be able to locate the print statements.

How do I do this in Scala, short of "println"?

Comment: what do you mean? If you want to debug properly, use a debugger. Else, use println statements or read the code..

Comment: @pedrorijo91 - This is better than println statements. https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/scala-trace-debug/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score -1):

Use this tool: https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/scala-trace-debug

^ It's really handy for tracing values, containers, expressions, etc. ^

---

If you want something a little more plain text editor friendly, try:

https://github.com/lihaoyi/sourcecode or https://github.com/lihaoyi/Ammonite

---

It's good for debugging things like multiple threads, separate processes, or anywhere else where debuggers tend to choke. Combine it with a debugger/logger.